# Busy/wait or spinning pattern in multithreaded environment

Tags: c++, multithreading

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-do-i-design-high-frequency-trading-systems-its-part-silahian-2/

> avoiding cache misses and CPU’s context switching

1. how does busy/wait and spinning pattern avoids context switches if it runs two threads in one core ?
   It will still have context switches between these two threads(producer thread and 1 consumer thread) right ?
2. what are the consequences if I don't set thread affinity to one specific core ?

I completely get why it avoids cache misses. But i am still having trouble how does it solve avoiding context switches.

Comment: (1) is said with the assumption there are enough cores.

Comment: You say "it will context switch if there's only 1 core". Yes, it will. Your quote assumes that the threads run on separate cores.

Comment: but the article said it avoids context switches, how ?

Comment: Because sleeping or waiting on a mutex is a context switch, while spinning on a spinlock is not.

Comment: there is 6 threads in that specific core, which means if any of those to run you need context switches right ?

Comment: Please read my second comment again. The quote is made under assumption that there is more than one core, maybe each thread having its own core. If there is only core, then yes, there shouldn't be much benefit.

Comment: Read your quoted article again. "*That means, that we will say to our system to run this busy/wait process in only one CPU core (could be core 1, 2, 3, etc). And we will be able to “pin” as many processes as CPU cores we have.*" Means you have x processes running on x cores. Not x processes running on single core.

Comment: yep louis Go thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does busy/wait and spinning pattern avoids context switches if it runs two threads in one core ?

When a thread perform a lock and the lock is taken by another thread, it make s system call so the OS can know that the thread is waiting for a lock and this should be worthless to let it continue its execution. This causes system call and a context switch (because the OS will try to execute another threads on the processing unit) which are expensive.

Using a spin lock somehow lies to the OS by not saying the thread is waiting while this is actually the case. As a result the OS will wait the end of the quantum (time slice allocated to the thread) before doing a context switch. A quantum is generally pretty big (eg. 8 ms) so the overhead of context switches in this case does not seems a problem. However, it is if you care about latency. Indeed, if another thread also use a spin lock, this cause a very inefficient execution because each thread will be executed during the full quantum and the average latency will be half the quantum which is generally far more than the overhead of a context switch. To avoid this happening, you should be sure that there are more core than thread to be actively running and control the environment. Otherwise, spin locks are actually more harmful than context switches. If you do not control the environment, then spin locks are generally not a good idea.

If 2 threads running on the same core and 2-way SMT is enabled, then each thread will likely be executed on each of the hardware thread. In this case spin locks can significantly slow down the other thread while doing nothing. The x86-64 pause instruction can be used to tell to the processor that the thread is doing a spin lock and let the other thread of the same core be executed. This instruction also benefit from reducing contention. Note that even with the pause instruction, modern processor will run at full speed (possibly in turbo frequency) causing them to consume a lot of energy (and so heat).

> what are the consequences if I don't set thread affinity to one specific core ?

Threads can then move between cores. If a thread move from one core to another it generally needs to reload data to its cache (typically fill the L2 from the L3 or another L2 cache) during cache misses that may occur on the critical path of a latency-critical operation. In the most critical cases, a thread can move from one NUMA node to another. Data transfer between NUMA nodes are generally slower. Not to mention the core will then access to data own by the memory of another NUMA node which is more expensive. Besides, it can increase the overall cost of context switches.

Comment: So i am gonna be running each busy/wait process in seperate core. 
One last doubt, If you have seen the code in that article you would have noticed locks in both producer and consumer threads which means context switch to the OS which will suspend threads waiting on this lock until it is released. So even if I runs each busy/wait process in seperate cores i still have that context switches right ? @Jérôme Richard

Comment: Well as long as there are ready threads in the scheduling queue, yes, there will be context switches. In practice there is often few ready threads doing some small work per seconds (eg. daemons like ssh, the init process, systemd, IRQ handling, etc.). On my Linux 6-core PC a basic test show 1-5 context-switch/s for a basic computing process (without locks). When all cores are filled with other computation I reach 40-42 switch/s. The quantum is quite big. Since a context switch takes no more than dozens of us, the chance of having a switch during a latency critical operation is pretty small.

Comment: Note the locks are only a problem when the thread is waiting on it. With a process doing a lot of very small sleep operation or a lock of locks requiring ping-pong operations, I got 15000-16000 switch/s. When all cores are used by another process, this reach 18000-19000 on my PC. You really not want this to happen in a latency critical operation ;) (unless dozens of microseconds is not a problem to you).

Comment: By the way, while 40-42 context switch does not seems a lot, one should also take into account that the waiting time between two switch was of few dozens of ms so the number of context switches is not the only thing to consider. This is the overhead to pay when spin locks are used and there are more active spin locks than PU (ie. hardware threads).

Comment: So imagine :
I run 1 producer thread in core 1.
I run 1 consumer thread in core 2.
Steps :

1) Producer thread acquires lock, and do the write process to the variable mtxdata.
2) while producer thread **has the lock** Consumer thread keeps spinning to avoid the context switches until locks available. 
3) When the lock is finally available to consumer thread it does the read process from variable **mtxdata**.

At 3rd step producer thread doesn't have the lock and it is not spinning to avoid context switches, which means context switch would happen in the core running producer thread ?

Comment: sorry for the ping, could you please clarify my above doubt please ?